# Cannot create wsClient after creating mock server via RoutingDsl

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaTestingWebServiceClients) on mocking an external web service:

```
Router router = new RoutingDsl().build();
Server server = Server.forRouter(router);
WSClient ws = WS.newClient(server.getHttpPort());
```

When creating the server, the Akka system is started. Logs mention some binding to 127.0.0.1:2551. I believe it's Netty, which is used by Akka.

When I create the WS client, some service (I believe Netty) also tries to bind to the same address and fails with `address already in use`.

I tried reconfiguring my Akka.remote in application.conf to use a different port, but both services appear to fight for the same port.

How can I get both the server and WS client to instantiate?

Thank you.

**Update - application.conf provided (comments and empty objects omitted)**

```
appName = myApplication

akka {
  log-config-on-start = true

  actor {
    provider = "cluster"
  }

  actor-system = ${appName}

  cluster {
    metrics {
      enabled = off
      native-library-extract-folder = ${user.dir}/target/native
    }

    pub-sub {
      name = distributedPubSubMediator
      role = ""
      routing-logic = broadcast
      gossip-interval = 1s
      removed-time-to-live = 120s
      max-delta-elements = 3000
      use-dispatcher = ""
    }

    seed-nodes = [
      "akka.tcp://"${appName}"@127.0.0.1:2551"
    ]
  }

  extensions = [
    "akka.cluster.metrics.ClusterMetricsExtension",
    "akka.cluster.pubsub.DistributedPubSub"
  ]

  remote {
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = on
    enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"] # needed ?
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 3551
    }
  }
}

play.crypto.secret = "mySecret"
play.modules {
  enabled += libs.clients.playaero.Module
  enabled += libs.clients.playelastic.Module
  enabled += libs.clients.playfacebook.Module
  enabled += controller.akka.Module
  enabled += model.Module
  enabled += settings.Module
}

play.i18n {
  langs = [ "en" ]
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need Akka remoting here? Isn't this just a unit test you're writing?

Comment: I have Akka configured for my project, but I did not enable it during the test. Akka was started when I did `Server.forRouter(router)`. So I guess Play's recommendation of using a mock server necessarily uses the Akka system.

Comment: Can you post your `application.conf` (and the one you use for your tests, if you use a separate one)?

Comment: @StefanoBonetti I updated the question with `application.conf`. My Akka config is for enabling multiple play server instances to communicate with each other. I did not expect this to interfere with instantiating a mock server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you anticipate, both `Server.fromRouter` and `WS.newClient` create a new Akka `ActorSystem` (note that `WS.newClient` has been deprecated as well for this reason, at least outside testing).

If Akka remoting is enabled, every spawned system will need its own port to listen on (as per [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/remoting.html)).

> The port number needs to be unique for each actor system on the same
>   machine even if the actor systems have different names. This is
>   because each actor system has its own networking subsystem listening
>   for connections and handling messages as not to interfere with other
>   actor systems.

The quickest solution would be to create an `application.conf` in your `test/resources` folder, bringing the settings back to local

```
akka.actor.provider = "local"
```